# Postgresql on Swisscom cloud

Tags: swisscomdev

I think Postgresql is part of the CloudFoundry services but I could not find it in the list of services for the Swisscom Cloud.
I would love to know if it will be added in the future ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Cloud Foundry Open Source developer, user and engineering community loves PostgreSQL. For example [our CI/CD pipeline](https://concourse.ci/binaries.html) doesn't support MariaDB. There are a lot of PostgreSQL fans working for the cloud project, but also some guys prefer MariaDB for non-technical reasons.

The official answer is something like this:

> Your inquiry concerns a feature that is not currently available in our
>   platform.  We do not comment on the availability of any new features.
>   We announce them when we are ready.  Your request as well as you
>   e-mail address were transferred to the Application Cloud Product
>   Management team.  They may try to contact you regarding the feature
>   you requested. We have aggressive road map for next few months and we
>   plan brining many exciting features for our customers.  We can only
>   say that much that Postgres is defiantly on our radar.  Follow our
>   announcements on twitter channel or on developer.swisscom.com.  Our
>   newsletter also provides frequent updates updates of the Application
>   Cloud.

Sorry for the management type answer.